# retain value of selected option even when refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value of a dropdown selected and pass the variable to javascript, that is working but aswell as that i am trying to save the value of a selected option even when the page is refreshed

i thought i could maybe create a cookie on a selected value and check if it exists.

any help would be appreciated

form

```
<form name="dummyForm">
    <select name="selectBox" onchange="getSelectedvalue()">
        <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
        <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
        <option value="option 3">option 3</option>
        <option value="option 4">option 4</option>
        <option value="option 5">option 5</option>
        <option value="option 6">option 6</option>
        <option value="option 7">option 7</option>
        <option value="option 8">option 8</option>
    </select>
</form>
<a href="javascript:setSelectBoxvalue()">Click me</a>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSelectedvalue()
{
    var getSelectedIndex = document.dummyForm.selectBox.selectedIndex;
    var getSelectedOptionText = document.dummyForm.selectBox[getSelectedIndex].text;
    alert(getSelectedOptionText);
}

function setSelectBoxvalue()
{
    var len = document.dummyForm.selectBox.length;
    //alert(len);
    var optionText= 'option 1';
    for(var i=0; i<=len; i++){
        if( (document.dummyForm.selectBox[i].value) == optionText){
            alert(document.dummyForm.selectBox[i].text);
            document.dummyForm.selectBox.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: so what is the problem with using a cookie ? your don't want to use one or don't know how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily manipulate cookies using the functions provided by the ever useful blog QuirksMode:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Here is how to implement your specific case (the example assums you assign an ID to the select of 'selectBox'):

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var cookieVal = readCookie('selectBoxValue');
    if(cookieVal!=null)
    {
        document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedIndex = cookieVal;
    }
}



function changeSelectedvalue()
{
    var mySelectedIndex = document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedIndex;
    createCookie("selectBoxValue",mySelectedIndex,1000);
}



function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

See the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpAm/9VmQD/

And the full screen version here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpAm/9VmQD/embedded/result/

Answer (score 3):

if there is HTML5 support use `localStorage`

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
  // Yes! localStorage and sessionStorage support!
  localStorage.paramName="value";
}
else
{
  // Sorry! No web storage support..
}
```

then get it like that:

```
var myParam = localStorage.paramName;
```

if there is no HTML5 support use cookies:

whit jQuery to set:

```
$.cookie("paramName", "value");
```

with jQuery to get

```
$.cookie("paramName");
```

without jQuery (although i don't know why not to use jQuery :P ) http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
        c_value = null;
    }
    else
    {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1)
        {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
```